# Драйвер или пакет для установки МФУ Panasonik KX-MB

Tags: драйвер, ubuntu, linux

Где взять драйвер или пакет для установки МФУ Panasonik KX-MB 1900 по Linux Ubuntu 10.04. ОС нормальная, но не могу подружить МФУ.

Answer (score 2):

Если производитель не позаботился о написании ПО, то свистопляски с бубном. У HP, например, все продумано: все ПО прямо из репозитория можно взять. Читайте их сайт. А [вот](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=164055.0) инфо по теме.